# IF function condition Subqueries all executed or conditioned only?

Tags: mysql

i have a query like this where i have over 1000 topics in table

```
SELECT
IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topics) > 1000,
        (SELECT MAX(id) FROM topics),
        (SELECT MIN(id) FROM topics)
) AS MMID
```

what i think is `COUNT(*)` runs first then `MAX(id)` runs after it

but i do not know if is `MIN(id)` is calculated too and has a cost on the performance

and does the same apply to `OR` conditions in `WHERE` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly irrelevant.  The `COUNT(*)` needs to scan through the table to get the count.  But `MIN` and `MAX` are each trivial -- find the first or last entry in the index.  (I am assuming you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.)

If you are likely to have a table that is much bigger than 1000 rows, this should run faster:  Change

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topics) > 1000
```

to

```
( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM topics LIMIT 1000,1 ) )
```

That should quit after scanning 1000 (or maybe 1001?) rows, returning essentially true/false.

`OR` is a different matter.

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE ...
       OR ...
```

essentially cannot use any index.  Instead, it must scan the entire table checking both expressions.  It *will* short-circuit the query, but it is unclear which side of the OR will be checked first.  I would *hope* (without any evidence) that it would decide that one side of the `OR` is clearly 'faster' and do it first (in hopes of getting `TRUE`).

`WHERE ... AND ...` does have specific known short circuits:  If one side is `MATCH...`, that will be performed first.

Comment: (I added a discussion of `OR`.)